# Resize frame around Verbatim

Tags: fancyvrb

The code:

```
 \begin{figure}
 \begin{Verbatim}[frame=single,
framesep=5mm]
<pick ...>
  <onMessage resolveByBPELEngine="true">
    ...
  </onMessage>
  ...
</pick>
\end{Verbatim}
\caption{Pick Activity}~\label{fig:ResolvingPickActivity}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

How could I resize the width to make it fit to the code inside? It is ok for setting a value for let say a width attribute statically.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is to use `fancyvrb`'s saving mechanism and then place the material in an `\fbox' appropriately defining the separation at that stage:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{SaveVerbatim}{VerbCode}
<pick ...>
  <onMessage resolveByBPELEngine="true">
    ...
  </onMessage>
    ...
</pick>
\end{SaveVerbatim}
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{5mm}
  \fbox{\BUseVerbatim{VerbCode}}
  \caption{Pick Activity}~\label{fig:ResolvingPickActivity}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The `SaveVerbatim` environment saves the contents in the given name, here `VerbCode`.  This is then reused with `\BUseVerbatim`.

Answer (score 2):

The `boxedverbatim`-environment of the `moreverb`-package does exactly this. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{moreverb}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{boxedverbatim}
<pick ...>
  <onMessage resolveByBPELEngine="true">
    ...
  </onMessage>
  ...
</pick>
\end{boxedverbatim}
\caption{Pick Activity}~\label{fig:ResolvingPickActivity}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note: If you want more sophisticated formatting (with syntax coloring etc), take a look at the `listings`-package (but no fitting of the box around the code, unfortunately)